# Memory of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, conditional-probability, bayesian

I was trying to understand the memory of a probability distribution, but couldn’t find any satisfactory answers online. Can somebody please explain what we mean by the memory of a probability distribution and how can we quantify it? I came across it while I was reading [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0020739820130510?journalCode=tmes20#:%7E:text=A%20concept%20of%20memory%20of,An%20application%20is%20also%20suggested.) paper.

Comment: A stochastic process is an object which associates a random variable with each time point. Thus there is a pdf of the variable for each time. The process is memoryless if the value of the process at time t does not depend on the value at earlier times. So the pdf at time t does not care what the pdf at earlier times looks like. Typically pdfs of stochastic processes with memory appear as convolution integrals of local pdfs across time. Analytical representations are relatively uncommon, however.

Comment: That paper is behind a paywall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability distributions with memory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261980/probability-distributions-with-memory)

Comment: probability distributions doesn't have memory. However some kind of stochastic processes we said that have memory when any random variable on the stochastic process is not independent from the previous ones, thus the process have a "memory", as the past shapes the present and the future